# R Markdown script does not always display result

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I have a problem with a RMD script. It runs. Once. After that, I get partial results.

The code:

````
---
title: "Dashboard"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
  runtime: shiny
---
```{r global, include=FALSE}
library(dplyr)
library(flexdashboard)
Name=c('Test1', 'Test1', 'Test2')
Number = c(8, 9, 7)
zt <- data.frame(Name, Number)
PersonList <- sort(unique(zt$Name))

```
Selections {.sidebar}
===============================
```{r}
## The shiny part
selectInput("PersonSel", "Person: ", PersonList, selected = 'Test1')
```
Tab 1
======================================================================
Row {.tabset}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
### Table
```{r}
renderTable({
cqi <- zt %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  filter(Name %in% input$PersonSel) %>%
  group_by(Number) %>%
  summarise(Count = n())
}, align='l')
```
````

Result:

[image: Result]
When I run the script again, I get this:

[image: Result 2]
In R Studio I see this:

[image: Studio]

But only this - it doesn't continue.

The only way to get it working again is to edit the script. Add a space or whatever.

Is seems very strange behavior. What can be the problem (and solution) here?